# Is it possible to merge but excluding certain revisions by SVN/Tortoise/Subclipse

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, subclipse

Assume a project has following revisions

```
rev 1000
rev 1001
..
rev 1008
...
rev 1011
...
rev 1015
```

Is it possible to have any non-manual solution to include all revision from `1000` to `1015` but exclude `1008` and `1011`? Tools or command from Subversion/Tortoise/Subclipse is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to specify the ranges of the revision you want to merge.  However, another way to do it is to "block" merging the revisions you do not want. You do this with the --record-only option.  The Subclipse merge UI has a specific UI option for this: Manually record merge information (Block one or more revisions).  With this option you go through the wizard and choose the specific revisions you do not want to merge (1008 and 1011).  When you finish, it records these revisions as having been merged in the merge info.  So now you can go back and merge all revisions in the range and SVN will skip over those two revisions as it assumes they have been merged already.

In the SVN Book this process is described here:  http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.blockchanges

Answer (score 2):

If you're using TortoiseSVN, the process is relatively simple:

1. Right click on the folder you're attempting to merge changes into.
2. TortoiseSVN > Merge...
3. Merge type should select "Merge a range of revisions" by default, so
   click next.
4. Specify the URL
5. In the Revision range to merge box, check specific range then use
   `1000-1007,1009-1010,1012-1015`
6. Then click **Next** and then **Merge**.

That will effectively merge all the changes except 1008 and 1011. Alternatively, you can use `1012-HEAD` if you don't mind merging everything after 1011.